# bootstrap navbar-brand align link text with svg

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, navbar

I'm trying to use bootstrap's  `.navbar-brand` class to have an svg in my navbar but I want text to be next to the svg and align it with that svg. I have the svg and text in the navbar but they don't align. Heres the code for the header.

```css
            nav a{
                color: white
            }
            nav {background-color: #1c71b9; z-index: 1;}
            .navbar-toggle{border: 3px solid white;}
            .icon-bar{background-color: white;}
            .navbar-brand:hover{background-color: white;
            color: #1c71b9;
            }
            body{margin-top: 50px; background-color: white;}
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p{
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
            }
            .row + .row{margin-top: 20px;}
            .itemHeading{font-weight: bold;}
            .icon{display: block; max-width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;}
            .descriptionHeading{margin-top: 20px; text-align: center;}
            .descriptionSection{background-color: #e5e5e5;}
            .mainDescriptionHeading{text-align: center;}
            .descriptionParagraph{text-align: center;}
            .centerDescriptionButton{padding-bottom: 20px;}
            .first-slide video{width: 100%;}
            .second-slide video{width: 100%;}
            .third-slide video{width: 100%;}
            .first-slide{width: 100%;}
            .second-slide{width: 100%;}
            .third-slide{width: 100%;}
            #myCarousel{margin-top: 50px;}
            .card{width: 100%; margin-bottom: 30px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px; padding: 15px; background-color: white;}
            .card video{width:100%;}
            .card-title{font-weight: bold;}
            
            .error{color: red;}
              .success{color: green;}
            .formQuestion{color: darkblue;}
            .overlay{position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
           }
            .overlay .videoButtonWrapper{
                flex-direction: row;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
                position: relative;
            }
            .videoBackgroundWrapper{position: relative; width: 100%;}
            .videoBackground{width: 100%;}
              .blue{color: darkblue; background-color: darkblue;}
            #signupApp{margin-top: 50px;}
            nav svg{ height: 100%; fill: white;}
            .navbar-brand{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
            .navbar-brand:hover>svg{height: 100%; fill: #1c71b9;}
            .formQuestion + .tooltip>.tooltip-inner{background-color: darkblue; font-weight:bold;}
            .success + .tooltip>.tooltip-inner{background-color: green; font-weight:bold;}
            .error + .tooltip>.tooltip-inner{background-color: red; font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
    <head>
    <!--vuejs-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="logInApp" v-cloak>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 171 171" style="enable-background:new 0 0 171 171;" xml:space="preserve">
        <path class="st0" d="M153.4,91l-30.2,8c-4.2,11.5-13.5,20.6-26.1,24.1c-20.7,5.7-42.2-6.5-48-27.2c-5.7-20.7,6.5-42.2,27.2-48
         c15.9-4.4,32.5,0.9,41.9,15.1l-19.5,5.3c-3.4-2.4-7.6-3.8-12-3.8c-11.6,0-20.9,9.4-20.9,20.9s9.4,20.9,20.9,20.9
         c8.5,0,15.8-5.1,19.1-12.3L153.5,81l0.7,0l11.4-6.7L163,62.6l-13.1-1.3l-4.3-9.1l7.3-11l-7.4-9.4l-12.4,4.5l-7.9-6.4l1.8-13.1
         l-10.7-5.2l-9.2,9.5l-9.8-2.3l-4-12.6L81.3,6.1l-4.2,12.5l-9.9,2.2l-9.1-9.6l-10.8,5.1L49,29.4l-7.9,6.2L28.7,31l-5.2,6.4l-2.3,2.9
         v0l7.2,11.1l-0.9,1.8l-3.6,7.3l-13.2,1.1L8,73.1L19.3,80l-0.1,10.1L7.9,96.9l2.6,11.6l13.1,1.3l4.3,9.1l-7.3,11v0l3.7,4.7l3.7,4.7
         l12.4-4.5l0.2,0.1l0,0l5.8,4.7l1.9,1.5l-1.8,13.1l10.7,5.2l9.2-9.5l9.8,2.3l4,12.6l11.9,0.1l4.2-12.5l9.9-2.2l9.1,9.6l10.8-5.1
         l-1.6-13.1l7.9-6.2l12.4,4.7l7.5-9.3l-7.2-11.1l4.4-9.1l13.2-1.1l2.7-11.6L154.1,91L153.4,91z"/>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 145.3561 17.4842)">TM</text>
       </svg>
     CreativeEngine</a>
            </div><!--end .navbar-header-->
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li v-show="admin==1"><a href="adminMenu.php">Admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subscriptions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Templates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stock</a></li>
                <li v-show="sesloggedin==0"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a></li>
                <li v-show="sesloggedin==1"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--end #navbar-->
         </div><!--end container-->
        </nav>
```

Comment: You can try to put the text in a span and style that div to the right position?

The SVG will always use the max height of the container. So aligning it with text the way you did above will be hard. I would recommend to put the text in a new container (such as a <span></span>) and style it to the right position.

Comment: can you send me a code snippet I'm not sure i know what you mean.

Comment: Posted, did that help you out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.logo-text { position:relative; top:-3px; margin-left:5px; }` to your CSS.
Then put the text (CreativeEngine) in a span and give it the class: "logo-text".

See the example below:

```css
            nav a{
                color: white
            }
            nav {background-color: #1c71b9; z-index: 1;}
            .navbar-toggle{border: 3px solid white;}
            .icon-bar{background-color: white;}
            .navbar-brand:hover{background-color: white;
            color: #1c71b9;
            }
            body{margin-top: 50px; background-color: white;}
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p{
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
            }
            .row + .row{margin-top: 20px;}
            .itemHeading{font-weight: bold;}
            .icon{display: block; max-width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;}
            .descriptionHeading{margin-top: 20px; text-align: center;}
            .descriptionSection{background-color: #e5e5e5;}
            .mainDescriptionHeading{text-align: center;}
            .descriptionParagraph{text-align: center;}
            .centerDescriptionButton{padding-bottom: 20px;}
            .first-slide video{width: 100%;}
            .second-slide video{width: 100%;}
            .third-slide video{width: 100%;}
            .first-slide{width: 100%;}
            .second-slide{width: 100%;}
            .third-slide{width: 100%;}
            #myCarousel{margin-top: 50px;}
            .card{width: 100%; margin-bottom: 30px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px; padding: 15px; background-color: white;}
            .card video{width:100%;}
            .card-title{font-weight: bold;}
            
            .error{color: red;}
              .success{color: green;}
            .formQuestion{color: darkblue;}
            .overlay{position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
           }
            .overlay .videoButtonWrapper{
                flex-direction: row;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
                position: relative;
            }
            .videoBackgroundWrapper{position: relative; width: 100%;}
            .videoBackground{width: 100%;}
              .blue{color: darkblue; background-color: darkblue;}
            #signupApp{margin-top: 50px;}
            nav svg{ height: 100%; fill: white;}
            .navbar-brand{margin: 0; padding: 0; position:relative; }
            .navbar-brand:hover>svg{height: 100%; fill: #1c71b9;}
            .formQuestion + .tooltip>.tooltip-inner{background-color: darkblue; font-weight:bold;}
            .success + .tooltip>.tooltip-inner{background-color: green; font-weight:bold;}
            .error + .tooltip>.tooltip-inner{background-color: red; font-weight:bold;}

.logo-text { position:relative; top:-3px; margin-left:5px; }
```

```html
    <head>
    <!--vuejs-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="logInApp" v-cloak>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 171 171" style="enable-background:new 0 0 171 171;" xml:space="preserve">
        <path class="st0" d="M153.4,91l-30.2,8c-4.2,11.5-13.5,20.6-26.1,24.1c-20.7,5.7-42.2-6.5-48-27.2c-5.7-20.7,6.5-42.2,27.2-48
         c15.9-4.4,32.5,0.9,41.9,15.1l-19.5,5.3c-3.4-2.4-7.6-3.8-12-3.8c-11.6,0-20.9,9.4-20.9,20.9s9.4,20.9,20.9,20.9
         c8.5,0,15.8-5.1,19.1-12.3L153.5,81l0.7,0l11.4-6.7L163,62.6l-13.1-1.3l-4.3-9.1l7.3-11l-7.4-9.4l-12.4,4.5l-7.9-6.4l1.8-13.1
         l-10.7-5.2l-9.2,9.5l-9.8-2.3l-4-12.6L81.3,6.1l-4.2,12.5l-9.9,2.2l-9.1-9.6l-10.8,5.1L49,29.4l-7.9,6.2L28.7,31l-5.2,6.4l-2.3,2.9
         v0l7.2,11.1l-0.9,1.8l-3.6,7.3l-13.2,1.1L8,73.1L19.3,80l-0.1,10.1L7.9,96.9l2.6,11.6l13.1,1.3l4.3,9.1l-7.3,11v0l3.7,4.7l3.7,4.7
         l12.4-4.5l0.2,0.1l0,0l5.8,4.7l1.9,1.5l-1.8,13.1l10.7,5.2l9.2-9.5l9.8,2.3l4,12.6l11.9,0.1l4.2-12.5l9.9-2.2l9.1,9.6l10.8-5.1
         l-1.6-13.1l7.9-6.2l12.4,4.7l7.5-9.3l-7.2-11.1l4.4-9.1l13.2-1.1l2.7-11.6L154.1,91L153.4,91z"/>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 145.3561 17.4842)">TM</text>
       </svg>
     <span class="logo-text">CreativeEngine</span></a>
            </div><!--end .navbar-header-->
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li v-show="admin==1"><a href="adminMenu.php">Admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subscriptions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Templates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stock</a></li>
                <li v-show="sesloggedin==0"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a></li>
                <li v-show="sesloggedin==1"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--end #navbar-->
         </div><!--end container-->
        </nav>
```

Comment: that only works on the md brakepoint other wise it pushes the image all the way to the left and the text isn't anywhere near it.

Comment: Removed the code and posted the new example which should work. :)

Comment: Yeah it worked great except when I go really small the line brakes and it doesn't line up as it should any ideas just when I go to xs size.

Comment: Make a media query. When your screen hits a certain with it scales down. P.s. I have to change my code. Put a span around the svg and style that would be better. It's bad to use minus in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.
Add the following lines to your CSS.

```
.icon {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-self: center;
}

.icon svg, .icon img {
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    fill: currentColor;
}

.icon.baseline svg, .icon img {
    top: .125em;
    position: relative;
}

h1 {
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:1;
    font-weight:normal;
  position:relative;
}

h1 {
  font-size:69px;
}
```

This would be the HTML

```
<h1>
   <div class="icon baseline">
      <svg width="58" height="58" viewBox="1 1 180 150">
         <path class="icon-info" d="M153.4,91l-30.2,8c-4.2,11.5-13.5,20.6-26.1,24.1c-20.7,5.7-42.2-6.5-48-27.2c-5.7-20.7,6.5-42.2,27.2-48 c15.9-4.4,32.5,0.9,41.9,15.1l-19.5,5.3c-3.4-2.4-7.6-3.8-12-3.8c-11.6,0-20.9,9.4-20.9,20.9s9.4,20.9,20.9,20.9 c8.5,0,15.8-5.1,19.1-12.3L153.5,81l0.7,0l11.4-6.7L163,62.6l-13.1-1.3l-4.3-9.1l7.3-11l-7.4-9.4l-12.4,4.5l-7.9-6.4l1.8-13.1 l-10.7-5.2l-9.2,9.5l-9.8-2.3l-4-12.6L81.3,6.1l-4.2,12.5l-9.9,2.2l-9.1-9.6l-10.8,5.1L49,29.4l-7.9,6.2L28.7,31l-5.2,6.4l-2.3,2.9 v0l7.2,11.1l-0.9,1.8l-3.6,7.3l-13.2,1.1L8,73.1L19.3,80l-0.1,10.1L7.9,96.9l2.6,11.6l13.1,1.3l4.3,9.1l-7.3,11v0l3.7,4.7l3.7,4.7 l12.4-4.5l0.2,0.1l0,0l5.8,4.7l1.9,1.5l-1.8,13.1l10.7,5.2l9.2-9.5l9.8,2.3l4,12.6l11.9,0.1l4.2-12.5l9.9-2.2l9.1,9.6l10.8-5.1 l-1.6-13.1l7.9-6.2l12.4,4.7l7.5-9.3l-7.2-11.1l4.4-9.1l13.2-1.1l2.7-11.6L154.1,91L153.4,91z"/>
         </path>
      </svg>
      </svg>
   </div>
   TM
</h1>
```

See this working pen at https://codepen.io/jdmarinv/pen/PBYeNK

Comment: the icon svgs arent the problem its the one in the navbar